# Linq to objects query collection and return difference

Tags: c#, linq

I have been struggling in writing some linq to object queries and wondering if you could help.

```
UPDATED AND SIMPLIFIED
```

1. output all properties that do not match on values within tempResult based on (Id and OrderNo)
   and put the result in a third list.

Many thanks!!!!

```
Setup

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Customer[] office1 =
            {
               new Customer {Id = 1,  OrderNo = 1, Name = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs", City = "London"},
                new Customer {Id = 2,  OrderNo = 2, Name = "Mark", Surname = "Smith", City = "Manchester"},
                new Customer {Id = 3,  OrderNo = 3, Name = "Emily", Surname = "Blunt",  City = "Liverpool"},
            };

            Customer[] office2 =
            {
                new Customer {Id = 1,  OrderNo = 1, Name = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs",  City = "London"},
                new Customer {Id = 2,  OrderNo = 2, Name = "Mark", Surname = "SmithError", City = "Manchester"},
                new Customer {Id = 3,  OrderNo = 4, Name = "EmilyError", Surname = "Blunt", City = "LiverpoolError"},
            };

            var customerOffice1 = office1.Except(office2);
            var customerOffice2 = office2.Except(office1);
            List<Customer> tmpResult = customerOffice1.Union(customerOffice2).ToList();

            //HOW DO i UPDATE THE FOLLOWING LIST WITH RESULT LIKE BELOW.
            List<Difference> diffs = new List<Difference>();

            Difference diff1= new Difference { Id = 2, PropertyName = "Surname", OldValue = "Smith", NewValue = "SmithError" };
            diffs.Add(diff1);
            Difference diff2 = new Difference { Id = 3, PropertyName = "Name", OldValue = "Emily", NewValue = "EmilyError" };
            diffs.Add(diff2);
            Difference diff3 = new Difference { Id = 3, PropertyName = "City", OldValue = "Liverpool", NewValue = "LiverpoolError" };
            diffs.Add(diff3);
        }

    }

    public class Difference
    {
        public int  Id { get; set; } 
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public string OldValue { get; set; }
        public string NewValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer : IEquatable<Customer>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int OrderNo { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Customer other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
            return string.Equals(Name, other.Name) 
                && string.Equals(Surname, other.Surname) 
                && string.Equals(City, other.City);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Customer) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hashCode = (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ (Surname != null ? Surname.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ (City != null ? City.GetHashCode() : 0);
                return hashCode;
            }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Customer left, Customer right)
        {
            return Equals(left, right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Customer left, Customer right)
        {
            return !Equals(left, right);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: cannot seemt to write a linq query that outputs what I want.
all my trying is giving wrong results

Comment: What results are you getting, what are your expected results? Please post a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: i did post what the wanted result should be in my question and you have all the setup too

Comment: Unfortunately on stackoverflow, there are people who are click happy and they like to downvote anything that they don't understand. When you hover to downvoting it says "This questions does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Well reading your question I can clearly see "you made a research effort". "it is not useful" -usefulness is up to you, "it is unclear" - may be the downvoter's criteria was this one, Except for why not the orderNo had any importance in difference despite you say 'based on Id and OrderNo' the question was clear to me.

Comment: thanks for your comment Cetin .I put too much effort in trying to explain the issue. All i want to know how to loop through a collections and compare properties based on id for now for semplicity

Comment: Yes, looking at your code and reading it again I can see what you need. If I have time and can solve it, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something like this (just for the matching IDs, for IDs that doesn't exist in the other you need to take care):

```
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Customer[] office1 =
            {
               new Customer {Id = 1,  OrderNo = 1, Name = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs", City = "London"},
                new Customer {Id = 2,  OrderNo = 2, Name = "Mark", Surname = "Smith", City = "Manchester"},
                new Customer {Id = 3,  OrderNo = 3, Name = "Emily", Surname = "Blunt",  City = "Liverpool"},
                new Customer {Id = 5,  OrderNo = 6, Name = "XX", Surname = "YY",  City = "ZZ"},
            };

    Customer[] office2 =
            {
                new Customer {Id = 1,  OrderNo = 1, Name = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs",  City = "London"},
                new Customer {Id = 2,  OrderNo = 2, Name = "Mark", Surname = "SmithError", City = "Manchester"},
                new Customer {Id = 3,  OrderNo = 4, Name = "EmilyError", Surname = "Blunt", City = "LiverpoolError"},
                new Customer {Id = 4,  OrderNo = 5, Name = "X", Surname = "Y", City = "Z"},
            };

    var customerOffice1 = office1.Except(office2);
    var customerOffice2 = office2.Except(office1);
    var diffIds = customerOffice1.Select(o => o.Id)
              .Intersect( 
                  customerOffice2.Select(o => o.Id) 
              );
    var difList = diffIds
      .SelectMany(i => customerOffice1.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == i)
      .GetDifference(customerOffice2.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == i)));
     // LinqPad
     // difList.Dump();
  }
}

public class Difference
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string PropertyName { get; set; }
  public string OldValue { get; set; }
  public string NewValue { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : IEquatable<Customer>
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public int OrderNo { get; set; }

  public List<Difference> GetDifference(Customer other)
  {
    return this.GetType().GetProperties()
      .Where(t => t.Name != "Id" && 
        t.GetValue(this).ToString() != t.GetValue(other).ToString() )
      .Select(t => new Difference { 
        Id = this.Id,
        PropertyName = t.Name,
        OldValue = t.GetValue(this).ToString(), 
        NewValue = t.GetValue(other).ToString()
        }).ToList();
  }

  public bool Equals(Customer other)
  {
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
    return string.Equals(Name, other.Name)
        && string.Equals(Surname, other.Surname)
        && string.Equals(City, other.City);
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
    return Equals((Customer)obj);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    unchecked
    {
      var hashCode = (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
      hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Surname != null ? Surname.GetHashCode() : 0);
      hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (City != null ? City.GetHashCode() : 0);
      return hashCode;
    }
  }

  public static bool operator ==(Customer left, Customer right)
  {
    return Equals(left, right);
  }

  public static bool operator !=(Customer left, Customer right)
  {
    return !Equals(left, right);
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Result:

```
Id PropertyName OldValue  NewValue

2 Surname       Smith     SmithError 
3 Name          Emily     EmilyError 
3 City          Liverpool LiverpoolError 
3 OrderNo       3         4
```

EDIT:
Only existing ID and OrderNo for q1:

```
var q1 = customerOffice1.Where(o => 
  office2.Any( o2 => o2.Id == o.Id && o2.OrderNo == o.OrderNo ))
  .Select(o => o.Id);
var difList = q1
  .SelectMany(i => customerOffice1.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == i)
  .GetDifference(customerOffice2.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == i)));
```

And this one is shorter IMHO:

```
var xxx = (from c1 in office1
          from c2 in office2
          where 
            c1.Id == c2.Id && 
            c1.OrderNo == c2.OrderNo &&
            c1 != c2
          select c1.GetDifference(c2)).SelectMany(d=>d);
```

Comment: Cetin you are so close .sorry for asking but customerId 3 should not appear on your result because there is no match on OrderNo.is it clear? getting paranoid now

Comment: I edited it for only those with matching Id and OrderNo.

Comment: Cetin.Really appreaciate your effort THANKS.. I get 1 result .is that what you where expecting

Comment: You are welcome. Although your question was about linq and doing that with reflection, this type of sample data reminds me some kind of database (and most Linq lists stem from a database). Many database engines already have some built-in method for "audit"ing the changes in data. They are mostly called "audit" and "diffgram", ie with an XML diffgram a record is listed with "BeforeValues" and "AfterValues" - where in case of an insert, BeforeValues is simply empty. Telling this in case it was database related.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I am able to have a stab at answering the first part of your question:

> Query 1 output all properties that do not match on values within tempResult based on (Id and OrderNo)

```
var diffs = office1.Zip(office2, (first, second) => Tuple.Create(first, second))
.Where(x => x.Item1.Id != x.Item2.Id || x.Item1.OrderNo != x.Item2.OrderNo);
```

This will return a collection of Tuples of customers which do not have matching Ids or Order numbers - with the Tuple containing both the mismatching customer's data.

I'm afraid that the second point is still not clear to me, so I am unable to help.

Comment: thanks for your time .Apologies if question is not clear I will  try to simplify and reedit. I get the same result as you .How do you output the results into a third class List<Difference> which i put in the question

Comment: Your Difference class has an Id property, but you are also checking to see if Ids differ. What should that value be if the Id is not the same?

Comment: if the Id in diff class does not match that we dont compare